# Duda sobre cookies php

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Cuando creo la sesion creo tambien una cookie la cual tiene 1min de duracion, esa cookie la creo para que cuando el usuario cierre el navegador y no hay cerrado sesion, al abrir el navegador este valide si existe la cookie y redirrecionarlo a la pagina, pero por alguna razon mientras voy navegando con la sesion abierta el tiempo de la cookie va pasando aun sin cerrar el navegador, por que pasa esto?

aqui el codigo:

```
public static function login ($data) {

    $user = Clear::Clearvars($data["user"]);
    $pass = Clear::Clearvars($data["pass"]);
    $query = Model::login($user, $pass);
    if (is_array($query)) {
        self::start_session($query);
    }else {
        echo json_encode(0);
    }
}

public static function start_session($query) {
    setcookie("user",$query["user"],time()+60);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"] = $query["user"];
}
```

el tiempo de la cookie empieza a correr una vez creada? o cuando uno cierre el navegador? porque recuerdo que corre cuando se cerraba, gracias :)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por que al abrir de nuevo mi navegador la cookie se sigue mostrando?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/365255/por-que-al-abrir-de-nuevo-mi-navegador-la-cookie-se-sigue-mostrando)

Comment: Por favor no dupliques preguntas.